# Strictly Identical arrays input

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

Any general tips to clean up this code?
just seems that I can accomplish the task w/o doing all the checks..

Thank you!

The txt book problem:
(strictly identical arrays) Two arrays list1[] and list2[] are strictly identical if they have the same length and list1[] is equal to list2[] for each[i].

write a function that returns true if list1 and list2 are strictly identical using the following header

```
  bool strictlyEqual(const int list1[], const int list2[], int size)
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter two lists of integers and dis­plays whether the two are strictly identical. The sample runs follow. Note that the first number in the input indicates the number of the elements in the list. This number is not part of the list. Assume the list size is maximum

My code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   bool strictlyEqual(int const list1[], int const list2[], int size);

   bool strictlyEqual (int x1[], int x2[], int n)
   {
     int f=0; int i;
     for (i =1; i<=n; i++)
     {
               if (x1[i] != x2[])
               {
                  // breaks loop
                    f=1;
                    break;
                }
     } 

 if (f==0)
 return (true);
 else 
 return(false);
 }


int main ()
cout << "enter list1: " << endl;
int list1[20], i;
cin >> list1[0];
for (i=1; i<= list1[0]; i++)
cin>> list1[i];

cout <<"enter the list2" << endl;
int list2[20];
cin >> list2[0];
for (i=1; i<= list2[0]; i++)
cin >> list2[i];

if (list1[0] == list2[0]
{
     int size = list2[0];
     bool v=strictlyEqual(list1, list2, size);
     if (v== true)
     cout << "identical" << endl;
     else 
     cout << "not identical " << endl;
 }

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should add spaces between array elements `5 5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Thank you! Any general tips to clean up this code ? just seems a little messy..

Comment: still I can't understand what's your problem? error?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto No error. Your suggestion about the spaces seems to have done the trick. Just asking for any general tips to clean up this code?
just seems that I can accomplish the task w/o doing all the checks.. Thank you

Comment: You should post on [codereview.se] if you have working code that you would like feedback on.

Comment: @MilesBudnek got it. should i delete this post ?

Comment: @walletfiber In it's current form, yes; I don't think it's a good fit for SO.  In its original form it had a question that's appropriate for this site, but that got answered in the comments.

Comment: Sane indentation works wonders to clean up code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be using [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) function.

```
int memcmp ( const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2, size_t num );
```

> Compares the first `num` bytes of the block of memory pointed by `ptr1` to the first `num` bytes pointed by `ptr2`, returning zero if they all match or a value different from zero representing which is greater if they do not.

```
bool strictlyEqual (int x1[], int x2[], int n){
    return memcmp(x1, x2, n * sizeof(int)) == 0;
}
```